# GetFrom is not implemented in MongoPersistenceEngine

Tags: neventstore

Upgraded from EventStore to NEventStore(4.1.0.0) today, now getting error.

My Error -

```
Method 'GetFrom' in type 'NEventStore.Persistence.MongoPersistence.MongoPersistenceEngine' 
from assembly 'NEventStore.Persistence.MongoPersistence, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
does not have an implementation.
```

Repro linked here - https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/issues/285

EDIT: In an effort to figure out why I'm having this issue, I went ahead and deleted the nuget package, downloaded the sources, attached the NEventStore core and MongoPersistence projects, and asside from some errors due to Nservicebus not being setup, everything works.

I think there might be an error in the current nuget package that was fixed after it was published.

EDIT2: same exception in the myget ci package

Comment: Having same TypeLoadException when NServiceBus tries to scan the Assemblies

Answer (score 0):

Seems as the NEventStore.Persistence.MongoPersistence 5.0.0.9 build at NuGet is broken. Current working solution is to download the Source from GitHub and recompile it.

https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/